# How to display select field values (combobox) from PostgreSQL db in openerp

Tags: odoo

with following code I could able to insert/edi trecord without any issue. My form view displays all fields except 'rate' which is selection field. Also tree view shows rate field as undefined. My database holds correct value for rate field. May I know the root cause for this and how to overcome this issue.

.py file is given here

```
from osv import osv
from osv import fields

class test_base(osv.osv):
     _name='test.base'
     _columns={
           'name':fields.char('Name'),
           'email':fields.char('Email'),

           'code':fields.integer('Unique ID'),
            sal':fields.float('Salary'),
           'rate':fields.selection(((10,'10'), (20,'20'),(30,'30')),
           'Percentage of Deduction'),
           'ded':fields.float('Deduction'),
           'bdisplay':fields.float('Button Display'),

           }

    def on_change_ded_cal(self, cr, uid, ids,rate,context=None):
        x=rate*2
        return {'value':{'ded':x }}


test_base()
```

My XML is

```
   <record model="ir.ui.view" id="test_base_form">
       <field name="name">test.base.form</field>
           <field name="model">test.base</field>
           <field name="type">form</field>
           <field name="arch" type="xml">
               <form string="Test Base">                       
                   <field name="name"/>
                   <field name="email"/>
                   <field name="code"/>
                   <field name="sal"/>
                   <field name="rate" on_change="on_change_ded_cal(rate,sal,ded)"/>
                   <field name="ded"/>                       
                   <field name="bdisplay"/> 
                  <button name="my_button_display" string="Calculate" type="object"/>
                     <newline />
                     <newline />
                     <newline />
                    <field name="skillid"  colspan="4"  nolabel="1"/>                          
                  </form>
          </field>
    </record>
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="test_base_tree">
        <field name="name">test.base.tree</field>
        <field name="model">test.base</field>
        <field name="type">tree</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Test Base">               
               <field name="name"/>
                <field name="email"/>
                <field name="code"/>
                <field name="sal"/>          
                <field name="ded"/> 
                <field name="rate"/>    
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]for your selection field you have to write like this:

you have missed string in selection fields

rate':fields.selection([(10,'10'), 
                        (20,'20'),
                        (30,'30')],'Rate'),

hope this help

Comment: Sorry friend!  my code has string and same is given below . 'rate':fields.selection(((10,'10'), (20,'20'),(30,'30')),'Percentage of Deduction'),

Comment: Can I get your email to send my module as attachment

Comment: jamesbaleme@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks. Mail has been sent to you along with steps to follow

Comment: hi, i found the bug in your module, in onchange method you have return True value which is incorrect, onchange method never return true, it is always return return {'value':{'ded':x}} like this, so you can change in you code something like this: 'def on_change_ded_cal(self, cr, uid, ids,rate,sal,ded,context=None):
     x = 0.0
        if rate:
         
            x=rate*sal
            x=x/100
        return {'value':{'ded':x}}'

Comment: onchange never return True it always return dict of values

Comment: Hi  Thanks for your effort. I made some changes even then selection field is not showing up...if possible can you provide code for the same with indentation. Even mail will do

Comment: i will send you working module, please do changes in this module

Comment: so please mark as question complete by checking Right Mark as under answer

Comment: Hey I don't see Right Mark under correct answer since correct answer was added as a comment. Will you please take a look.  Correct answer is -[sic]  hi. i found the bug....